# Network problems with Ubuntu Server 12.10

Tags: installation, 12.10, networking, server

Hey guys im new to the world of ubuntu from what ive been doing so far there is loads of help and it been grate but now ive hit a problem.

I am running Ubuntu Server 12.10, and my connection speed is not playing ball. My router is tell me that i have download speeds of 8MB/s but when i download some thing through the server im only getting around 300Kb/s. I'm using an Cat6 Ethernet cable to connect my server to the router and my network card is able to gain speeds of upto 1GB/s. This is also some thing im struggling to figure out every example i have looked at you all use eth0 etc. My connection on the other hand is showing:

```
ultrabeat@minetechmc:~$ ifconfig -a
    p131p1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:43:00:13:9b
          inet addr:192.168.1.123  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::250:43ff:fe00:139b/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:373282 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:199898 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:561559942 (561.5 MB)  TX bytes:13461545 (13.4 MB)
          Interrupt:19

# The primary network interface
auto p131p1
iface p131p1 inet dhcp
```

Would this be the problem and if so can anyone shed some light on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Is your router saying 8MB/s or 8Mb? is it cable or ADSL? Internet download speeds are dependant on alot more than link speed. Things like congestion at your ISP as well as remote server load. This speed does not sound abnormal.

What are local copies like? The info provided looks fine. Dont worry about eth0 etc.. They are just names assigned to the NIC . eth0, eth1 etc.. yours likely has a name derived from the module or model of card.